# Is there a way to rotate a canvas object around its bottom point rather than its center point

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am making a game using html, and I need to rotate a canvas object with the bottom of the rectangle as the centerpoint, however i'm not sure if this is possible through the rotate method. Any ideas on how to get this working? Thanks.

```
function drawRotatedRect(x, y, width, height, degrees, color) {
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.translate(x + width / 2, y + height / 2);
    context.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
    context.rect(-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fill();
    context.restore();}
```

Comment: Have a think about what the third line of the function actually does - the `translate` one.

Comment: solved, it had to do with the creation of the rectangle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use beginPath and and fill for rectangle you can use fillRect or strokeRect. Also you can avoid the sometime slow save and restore functions if you set the transform. If you only use setTransform you will not need to use save and restore for anything but clipping.

A quicker version of your code.

```
// where centerX and centerY is where the rotation point is on the rectange    
function drawRotatedRect(x, y, width, height, centerX, centerY, rotation, color) {
    context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
    context.rotate(rotation);
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fillRect(-centerX, -centerY, width, height);
    context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // restore default Only needed if 
                                            // you transform not using setTransform 
                                            // after this call
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with the first 2 parameters of the creation of the rectangle, solved